# Generic Casting

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I suspect the answer is no, but is it possible to do something like this in C#.NET (v2.0).

```
class Converter<E>
{
    public E Make(object o)
    {
        return o as E;
    }
}
```

If not, is it possible to check types like this:

```
public bool IsType(object o, Type t)
{
    return o is E;
}
```

I'm not certain about the terminology so it is rather hard to Google for me. 
But my guess is that these two problems are related. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast `o` to `E` using the [**()** Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx):

```
class Converter<E>
{
    public E Make(object o)
    {
        return (E)o;
    }
}
```

If you use [**as**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), `o as E` requires `E` to a be a reference type, because if `o` is not castable to `E`, the result is `(E)null`. You can constrain `E` to reference types by using the [**class** Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
class Converter<E> where E : class
{
    public E Make(object o)
    {
        return o as E;
    }
}
```

---

```
public bool IsType(object o, Type t)
{
    return (o != null) ? t.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()) : t.IsClass;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not relevant here, but `as` also works on nullable value types. So for example `o as int?` does compile.

Comment: Note that in your first example, if E is a non-nullable value type then the unboxing conversion must be exact; that is, if the object contains a boxed int you may not unbox it to double, even though you can convert an int to double.