# Force C# Cast To Generic

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

There is a tool I'm modifying as I want to be able to use a generic type.
It has properties "AsDouble", "AsBool", etc.

I want to force a typecast and I don't care if it throws in runtime. I just want it to compile.

So... this does not compile...

```
public T As<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(Double))
    {
        return (T)(AsDouble);
    }
    // more conditionals
}
```

Yet this does...

```
public T As<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type == typeof(Double))
    {
        return (T)(AsDouble as object);
    }
    // more conditionals
}
```

Why is it acting like this? How do I make it stop complaining and just do what I ask it too? Or is there a much better way of doing this than what I have in mind?

// Not duplicate of the one suggested. (Type1)Type2 does not work... I am wondering why converting from T1 to T2 to T3 works but not T1 to T3. (T1 being double, T2 being object, T3 being generic type.) Please read my question before flagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: AsDouble is a complex type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443951/generic-casting)

Comment: No, AsDouble is a property that returns the variable as a 'double'. It just attempts to Convert and TryParse.

Comment: Why are you doing this when `System.IConvertible` already exists?

Comment: System.IConvertible requires me to implement like 15 different methods. I don't need that many. It would be confusing too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` does not have any type constraints the compiler will not know what type of casting to do as the relation between `T` and `double` is not known. The only way I know to achieve what you want is to cast through object, which might generate a box/unbox operation (it might get optimized but I am not sure).

In the case of generic methods with clear specializations by type I have employed the following pattern:

```
class Owner
{
    class  AsHelper<T>
    {
        public static Func<Owner, T> As;
    }

    static Owner()
    {
        AsHelper<double>.As = _ => _.AsDouble;
        // Other implementations
    }
    public T As<T>() where T: struct
    {
        if(AsHelper<T>.As != null)
        {
            return AsHelper<T>.As(this);
        }
        else
        {
            // Default implementation or exception
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps the specializations in their own methods. From my performance testing it does about the same as the if base approach. Since statics are per generic class instantiation in .NET not per generic class definition the `As` field of `AsHelper<T>` will have a different value for each `T`

Comment: I've read this through a few times; and now I am understanding what you are saying. This is amazing! I have never thought of something like this before; thanks so much!

Comment: Glad yo help :)